# com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubFullscreenActivity: java.lang.ClassCastException: l8.o cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Tags: java, android, android-studio, interstitial, mopub

**MoPub SDK Version** :
5.18.0

**Android Studio Version** :
2020.3.1

**Gradle Version** :
7.0.0

**Device model and OS Version** :
android, any model and version

**Ad Unit IDs used in reproducing the issue** :
Interstitial

**Steps to reproduce the behavior** :
Crash produced in only my firebase crashlytics that put my App in bad behaviour.

**Crash Log** :

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.../com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubFullscreenActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: l8.o cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException: l8.o cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:320)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:188)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1302)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1485)
at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1470)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:206)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:159)
at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt__MutableCollectionsJVMKt.sort(CollectionsKt__MutableCollectionsJVMKt.java:31)
at com.mopub.mobileads.VastVideoConfig.addFractionalTrackers(VastVideoConfig.kt:223)
at com.mopub.mobileads.VastVideoViewProgressRunnable.(VastVideoViewProgressRunnable.kt:79)
at com.mopub.mobileads.VastVideoViewController.(VastVideoViewController.kt:306)
at com.mopub.mobileads.FullscreenAdController.createVideoViewController(FullscreenAdController.java:350)
at com.mopub.mobileads.FullscreenAdController.(FullscreenAdController.java:219)
at com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubFullscreenActivity.onCreate(MoPubFullscreenActivity.java:73)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8142)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8114)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3565)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3752)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2178)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8051)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)

Comment: Do you use proguard when building your app? did you check which proguard rules are required by MoPub?

Comment: MoPub platform is going to get deprecated